Fully coupled thermal-stress analysis in Abaqus/Standard- equations
I'm simulating a fully coupled thermal-stress problem with linear elastic material in Abaqus and comparing the results with my own implementation of the same problem in FEniCSx. The weak form in FEniCSx has been derived using the balance equations mentioned in the paper Farhat et al. (1991) Link, which are:
Screen shot of the balance equations
$$
\text{div}(\sigma) = 0, \\
\rho c_\varepsilon \dot{\theta} = \text{div}(k\,\text{grad}\,(\theta)) - \alpha(3\lambda+2\mu)\theta_0\text{tr}(\dot{\varepsilon})
$$
where,
$\sigma = 2\mu\varepsilon + \lambda\text{tr}(\varepsilon)\textbf{I} - \alpha(3\lambda+2\mu)(\theta - \theta_0)\textbf{I}$  and
${\varepsilon}= \frac{1}{2}\left(\text{grad}(\textbf{u}) + {\text{grad}(\textbf{u})}^T \right)$. Details on other parameters are fairly standard and can be found in the paper.
My FEniCSx results (both temperature and displacement fields) match to those of Abaqus only after I neglect the strain rate term in the heat conduction equation $\left(\alpha(3\lambda+2\mu)\theta_0\text{tr}(\dot{\varepsilon}) \right) $ thereby uncoupling the displacement from temperature change. This is in contradiction the Abaqus' analysis description which states that both fields are fully coupled.
Does anyone know which coupled equations does Abaqus/Standard implement for fully coupled thermal-stress analysis? Especially the heat conduction equation?
In the Abaqus theory manual I could only find the uncoupled heat conduction equation (link) but no equations on fully coupled thermal-stress analysis. However there is a description of the fully coupled thermal-stress analysis procedure in the Abaqus user manual (link).
Thank you for any leads.
